# regex for replacing all "abc" wtih "xyz"

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a regex that replaces all "abc" in a string with "xyz". Any hints? Or how to solve it in java with pattern and matcher? (need a regex too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
str = str.replaceAll("abc", "xyz");
```

It will work. `"abc"` is treated like a regex.

What also will work is

```
str = str.replace("abc", "xyz");
```

it will also replace **all** occurrences of `abc` with `xyz`, but `"abc"` is treated like a literal here.

Comment: +1 for also suggesting replace instead of regex option :)

Answer (score 1):

Method `replaceAll` class `String`
[Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex here. You can use simple [String#replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) like this:

```
String replaced = str.replace("abc", "xyz");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [**String.replaceAll(regex, str)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
    String s="abcfvabcb";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("abc", "xyz"));
```

Output:

```
  xyzfvxyzb
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the methods `replaceAll()` or `replace()`.

```
String s2 = s1.replaceAll("abc", "xyz");
```

[Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) on the `replaceAll` method.

---

**Differences between `replaceAll()` and `replace()`**

In `java.lang.String`, the `replace` method either takes a pair of char's or a pair of `CharSequence`'s (of which String is a subclass, so it'll happily take a pair of String's). The `replace` method will replace all occurrences of a char or `CharSequence`.

On the other hand, both `String` arguments to `replaceFirst` and `replaceAll` are regular expressions (regex). Using the wrong function can lead to subtle bugs.

Comment: note that replaceAll() takes regex as first param. in this case "abc" is indeed regex rather than a string literal

Comment: My answer states that...?

Comment: Your answer stated that un till you edited it :)

Comment: No, I edited it to separate the `replace` definition from the other definition.  It was always there :).